# Determine whether the following infinite sum converges or diverges

Tags: calculus

we want to study the following infinite sum

$$ \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ (\ln k)^{\ln k } }$$

My believe is that we should apply the integral test here:

$$ \int_2^{\infty} \frac{ dx}{ (\ln x)^{\ln x} } $$

Can write $ (\ln x)^{\ln x} = e^{\ln x \cdot \ln ( \ln x )}$. Let $ u = \ln x $, then $du = \frac{dx}{x}= e^{-u} dx $. Thus,

$$ \int\limits_{\ln 2 }^{\infty} \frac{ e^u du}{e^{u \ln u }}$$

And here I am stuck! Maybe should we estimate the above improper integral? perhaps using $e^x > x+1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For large k,

$$\ln k^{\ln k} = e^{\ln \ln  k \ln k}  = k^{\ln \ln k} >k^2$$